# Entity Framework Core: automate implement CRUD for each entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, crud, boilerplate

ORM is Entity Framework Core.
There are about 100 types of entities in DataModel. Is there a way to avoid typing boilerplate basic CRUD operations code for each of them?

```
public static async Task UpdateAsync(this Foo foo)
{
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        db.Foo.Update();
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

public static async Task UpdateAsync(this Bar bar)
{
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        db.Bar.Update(bar);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
How use generics in this case?

```
public static async Task RemoveFooAsync(int fooID)
{
     using (var db = new DBContext())
     {
          db.Foo.Remove(db.Foo.Single(x => x.FooID == fooID));
          await db.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
}
```

Comment: You could use generics? `UpdateAsync<T>(this T obj) where T : IMyEntity`

Comment: For the remove-by-id case, you would obviously need to have a general `Id` inside the `IMyEntity` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Frame Work itself is Generic hence you don't need to do that.

```
using (var dbCtx = new SchoolDBEntities())
    {
        //Add newStudent entity into DbEntityEntry and mark EntityState to Added
        dbCtx.Entry(newStudent).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

        // call SaveChanges method to save new Student into database
        dbCtx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

here the Entry param can be any type of <> Entity in App Db Context

Create such a reusable method using the Entity Object

Use Update the same way:

```
//save modified entity using new Context
using (var dbCtx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    //3. Mark entity as modified
    dbCtx.Entry(stud).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;     

//4. call SaveChanges
dbCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: does not matter , should be version 5 or higher

Comment: Also create a Parent class with generics for same such operations for all

Comment: You can also just do `db.Set<T>().Add(obj)` or `db.Set<T>().Update(obj)`.

Comment: @poke In EFC even `Set<T>()` or `T` is not needed - one can use `db.Add(obj)` or `db.Update(obj)`. But that doesn't really matter because the proposed "generic" (I would say naïve) approach works only with entities w/o any navigation property. Which in reality is rare.

Comment: @IvanStoev: the `Set<T>()` does become relevant if they're going to be using a generic repository that also gets data from the database. Not explicitly part of the question, but good to note nonetheless. I also disagree with the rarity of repositories that do not observe navigational properties. Many projects are built on repositories that only save the objects you ask it to save. We've been successfully using a `Repository<T>` class for quite some time.

Comment: @IvanStoev, @Niraj Sanghani are there any differencies between using `db.Update(obj);` and `db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;`? Both works with navigation properties in my case.

Comment: @AsValeO I think `db.Update(obj)` cascades, i.e. would also mark the referenced objects as modified. While the later will mark only the entity. At least this is how it was, I don't know if the behavior is changed in EFC 2.0

Comment: @IvanStoev, blagodarya!

Comment: Repository<T>  is the best way being used by most called the repo. Pattern.